# Generate random numbers with the same distribution as sample data

Tags: matlab, random, statistics, distribution

How to generate random numbers (in between minimum and maximum limits) using "Monte-Carlo" method with a specified distribution using Matlab ?

Our steps to solve the problem were:

1- Specify the sample distribution ('generalized extreme value' distribution "using mark allfitist()")

2- Find the parameters of the sample data

3- Make object of the required distribution

4- Truncate the distribution by Data's minimum and maximum

5- Generate n sample

6- Draw curve

7- Compare mean, standard deviation and parameters

Here's the code:

```
function [] = GenRand_gev(Data,size)
    Minimum=min(Data);
    Maximum=max(Data);
    Data_Mean = mean(Data);
    Data_Standard_Diviation = std(Data);
    % get the parameters
    LN= mle(Data,'distribution','generalized extreme value');
    Data_K=LN(1);
    Data_sigma=LN(2);
    Data_mu=LN(3);
    % make object of the required distribution
    pd_gev = makedist('generalized extreme value','K',Data_K,'sigma',Data_sigma,'mu',Data_mu);
    % Truncate the distribution by minimum and maximum
    t= truncate(pd_gev,Minimum,Maximum);
    % generate n sample
    r = random(t,size,1);
    % draw distribution curve
    histfit(r,[],'generalized extreme value');
    legend('Generated sample','distribution curve');
    Gen_Mean = mean(r);
    Gen_Standard_Diviation = std(r);
    LN1 = gevfit(r);
    Gen_k=LN1(1);
    Gen_sigma=LN1(2);
    Gen_mu=LN1(3);
end
```

and

```
Data=[104.24
62.58
96.9
63.12
62.8
23.64
61.06
23.62
61.42
23.6
61.68
23.64
62.32
23.6
62.5
23.1
68.16
27.36
72.9
27.3
76.4
27.28
76.48
26.58
76.54
27.38
76.78
27.48
76.82
27.32
76.82
26.96
79.86
26.86
80.36
26.92
80.44
27.9
80.56
24.38
80.6
26.68
81.62
26.58
80.9
26.88
82
23.76
84.78
29.14
88.24
29.04
95.28
28.54
96.28
27.26
99.72
28.48
101.06
28.82
102.84
28.72
103.52
28.18
103.76
28.5
103.88
28.86
104.02
28.68
104.04
28.46
104.66
29.3
105.52
28.48
105.64
25.18
25.65
25.65
25.8
29.23
69.33
69.29
69.25
69.07
68.3
]
```

Is this correct??

When comparing the  Mu, Sigma and the parameters of the sample data and the generated numbers (Data_Mean & Gen_Mean), (Data_Standard_Diviation & Gen_Standard_Diviation), (Data_K & Gen_k), (Data_sigma & Gen_sigma), (Data_mu & Gen_mu) for different sizes they found to be very different.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can not copy paste your function to make it work.

Comment: What is `t`? It is not defined in your function. Also using `size` as a variable name is a very bad idea as it masks the extremely useful built-in function. Also which K, Sigma and Mu are in your table? `LN` or `LN1`?

Comment: @Ander Biguri  Sorry there was a missing line in the code, it should be working now

Comment: @user3332603 no its not. Try it yourself. Close MATLAB, open MATLAB copy and paste the code and run. `Data` doesnt exist

Comment: @user3332603 stackoverflow doesn't do syntax highlighting for MATLAB which is why I put the `//` in for your comments. I suggest you put them back to make it more readable on the site. They won't affect your code.

Comment: @Dan I've defined t now. K, Sigma and Mu are the generalized extreme value parameters for the data and the generalized numbers according to the generated size

Comment: @user3332603 So the first line of the table is `Data_K` etc and the rest are `Gen_k`? I suggest you post the code to generate that table and also some sample data. What happens if you don't `truncate`?

Comment: @Ander Biguri Data should be defined first when calling the function. it's an array of 87 value (edited in he question). and this's who you call the function: GenRand_gev(Data,1000)

Comment: @user3332603 add the script that you used to generate the table as well. And try it without the truncation.

Comment: @Dan that's right. I posted the data but the table doesn't have  code, I've made it to conclude the results from different trails

Comment: Maybe your code is rigth, but your data doesnt follow any of the distributions you tried

Comment: @AnderBiguri that shouldn't matter for the last 3 parameters (the actual mean and std seem like bad choices to measure) since the code should generate distributions with the parameters it finds regardless of whether those parameters accurately model the data. I suspect the problem is due to the truncation.

Comment: @Dan without truncate the generated data will be i the range of [0,1]

Comment: @user3332603 yes but no one here is going to sit and manually run your code at different sample sizes and compile their own table of numbers. Write a script and post it. Besides, how do we know that your error isn't between running the function and printing to that table.

Comment: @user3332603 without truncate, do your parameters match? Test it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've used mark's function "allfitist()" to get the best distribution that fits my data, isn't it reliable??

Comment: @Dan without truncate neither the Mean , standard deviaion nor the parameters match

Comment: @Dan if the actual mean and std seem like bad choices to measure, then how to evaluate the generated numbers??

Comment: @user3332603 Well you use maximum likelihood estimates so why not just stick with those? But that's a stats question and it's better to ask at [stats.se]

Comment: @Dan how to stick with mle ? isn't it used to estimate the parameters

Comment: Without the `truncate` command the parameters of a generalized extreme value distribution fitted to `r` (k, sigma, mu) perfectly match the parameters of the generalized extreme value distribution fitted to your data. The mean and standard deviation will only match if the distribution is a good fit to your data, and I don't think that it is. This seems to be more of a stats question that a MATLAB question.

Comment: @ zelanix how to limit the generated data between the minimum and maximum values without trancate?

Comment: @user3332603, of course you can truncate the distribution, but then you can't expect the distribution parameters to be the same. Say I take a uniform distribution between 0 and 1: the mean is obviously 0.5. If I truncate it at 0 and 0.5 then the mean will be 0.25. But also, how sure are you of the limits of the distribution? Are you sure that your small sample set contains the entire range of the possible data? if so, have you chosen an appropriate distribution to model the data?